# Latitude and longitude displayed on a UILabel

Tags: swift, geolocation, uilabel

Hi I just need some help retrieving the latitude and longitude of the users location and being able to display it on a UILabel.
I’m pretty new to swift and I know how to recieve the values because I’ve used void functions but actually displaying them is what’s getting me

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

Answer (score 0):

## You can use core location to do this as follows

### 1. Providing a Proper Description

To gather location changes data, you need to set two special strings in the Info.plist file
[image: Imahe]
Then do this

```
import CoreLocation

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var coordinatesLabel: UILabel!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        guard status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            // Handle when no access
            return
        }
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first?.coordinate else { return }
        coordinatesLabel.text = "Lat: \(location.latitude), Lng: \(location.longitude)"
    }
}
```